# How do I convince UnmarshalJSON to work with a slice subtype?

Tags: json, go, reflection, marshalling, slice

I want byte slices that marshal and unmarshal in JSON using [base64](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#pkg-constants) `RawURLEncoding` instead of `StdEncoding`. There's no obvious way to do this through the [encoding/json package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/), which is sensible, so I thought I'd create a subtype to do it.

```
type Thing []byte
```

Marshaling support is easy:

```
func (thing Thing) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if thing == nil {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return []byte(`"` + base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(thing) + `"`), nil
}
```

But Unmarshal not so much. I traced the [encoding/json source](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go#L911), and came up with:

```
func (thing Thing) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(&thing)
    if len(data) == 0 || data[0] == 'n' { // null
        v.SetBytes([]byte{})
        return nil
    }
    data = data[1 : len(data)-1]
    dst := make([]byte, base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodedLen(len(data)))
    n, err := base64.RawURLEncoding.Decode(dst, data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    v.SetBytes(Thing(dst[:n]))
    return nil
}
```

But yields a panic in the call to `SetBytes()`:

```
panic: reflect: reflect.Value.SetBytes using unaddressable value [recovered]
    panic: reflect: reflect.Value.SetBytes using unaddressable value
```

I tried using a pointer to a slice, instead, which works (and doesn't require reflection), but causes other challenges elsewhere in my code that wants to work with slices instead of pointers.

So two questions, I guess:

1. Is this the best way to go about getting byte slices to marshal using `RawURLEncoding`?
2. If so, how can I convince my byte slice subtype to reference the data decoded from the `RawURLEncoding` format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code to unmarshal the value:

```
func (thing *Thing) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
  if len(data) == 0 || data[0] == 'n' { // copied from the Q, can be improved
    *thing = nil
    return nil
  }
  data = data[1 : len(data)-1]
  dst := make([]byte, base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodedLen(len(data)))
  n, err := base64.RawURLEncoding.Decode(dst, data)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  *thing = dst[:n]
  return nil
}
```

The key points:

- Use a pointer receiver.
- Reflection is not needed to assign a []byte to a Thing.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/7Hmk5VOVyq)

Comment: Well I'll be damned. It hadn't occurred to me to use a pointer *just for `UnmarshalJSON`, but that does in fact work! Only change I made was for the `null` case to set it to `nil` instead of an empty byte slice. Works great, thanks!

Comment: Hrm, now trying to get it to work as a JSON object key, but it doesn't like my `UnmarshalText`. It's just like `UnmarshalJSON` (except for the quotation marks), but when I try to unmarshal into a `map[*Thing]string`, `Unmarshal` says `json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type map[*Thing]string`.  [Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/rxmvOVa8MW).

Comment: @theory A `*Thing` is not a useful map key in this scenario (you get a new *Thing for every decoded value).  Declare `Thing` as a `string` type to use it as a map key.   See https://play.golang.org/p/P94GfU2jr3